# Quelle est la différence entre crédulité et naïveté?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes

C'est une simple question que je me pose alors que je me prépare à rédiger un article.

La crédulité et la naïveté, sont-elles réellement des synonymes?

Jusqu'à maintenant, je pensais qu'être crédule, c'est être une personne qui croit facilement n'importe quelle information qu'on lui communique. C'est à dire, limité au domaine de **l'information et de la connaissance** comme un article ou une histoire, écrite ou orale.

Par exemple: "Sais-tu qu'il y a de l'or au pied d'un arc-en-ciel?" et le crédule répondra: "Wow, c'est génial, je ne savais pas".

D'un autre côté, je pensais qu'être naïf, c'est être une personne qui croit, assimile ou associe **n'importe quoi** facilement, c'est à dire une information, une action, un sourire, une parole qui semble communiquer une information ou un sentiment qui est tout autre mais qui n'est pas forcément une information qui a pour but de "t'apprendre" quelque chose.

Par exemple: "La jolie demoiselle de la boulangerie m'a souri et m'a offert un petit pain en plus." Le naïf croirait que la jolie demoiselle ressent une certaine affection pour lui. En réalité, il pourrait ne s'agir que d'un comportement commun avec tout le monde pour satisfaire le client et favoriser son retour. Pour moi dans ce cas, je n'utiliserais pas crédule, mais naïf, car il ne s'agit pas d'une transmission de connaissances.

Voilà, mes exemples ont-ils un sens, et pouvez-vous m'aider?

Answer (score 5):

Il me semble que ton approche du problème est correcte. Ce sont des notions proches, mais crédule est péjoratif et se limite à la transmission de connaissance, naïf ne l'est pas forcément, et se dit de quelqu'un qui voit les choses d'une manière simple, avec des yeux d'enfant.

Ce ne sont donc pas des synonymes, car on peut être crédule pour des raisons de défaut de connaissance ou d’intelligence, sans pour autant être naïf, et on peut être naïf tout en sachant déceler la fausse information, et donc ne pas être crédule.

Tes exemples ont donc bien un sens, et le client naïf de la boulangerie prouve bien qu'être naïf (dans son cas car aveuglé par l'amour) ne signifie pas être crédule.

Comment: C'est ainsi que je vois les choses, malheureusement, comme l'indique Circeus dans sa réponse, il semble que cette différence n'est pas indiquée par les professionnels. Le point commun serait donc une trop grande confiance ou facilité à croire ou penser quelque chose. Mais leur emploi n'est pas toujours interchangeable et dépend de la nature de ce "quelque chose".

Comment: Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec Circeus dans le sens que ce n'est pas parce que deux mots peuvent servir à se définir mutuellement que ça fait d'eux des synonymes. Je dirai finalement que leur point commun est une trop grande facilité à croire une information, c'est à dire que leur point commun est la crédulité. Autrement dit la crédulité est une certaine forme de naïveté, mais la naïveté n'implique pas forcément la crédulité.

Answer (score 3):

Les deux mots sont synonymes dans la plupart des contextes.

En utilisant "crédule" tu insistes sur le fait que la personne est prête à croire à tout. Ceci est assez adapté quand tu veux mettre en valeur le fait qu'un mensonge a été pris pour vérité et que la personne crédule n'a pas fait l'effort ou n'a peut-être même pas eu l'idée d'une démarche critique. "Crédule" peut également mettre en valeur la bêtise du manipulé ou du moins sa faiblesse.

En revanche, en utilisant "naïf" tu insistes plus sur la candeur que la "victime". Il y a dans le mot "naïf" l'idée de la candeur, de l’innocence, du naturel, de l'absence d'artifice... D'ailleurs on peut dire "Les grâces naïves de l’enfance." Naïf est un mot plus large en sens et n'est pas toujours utilisé avec une connotation négative (On ne peut pas en dire autant de "crédule"). "Naïf" met en valeur le déséquilibre du rapport de force et donne d'avantage le tord au manipulateur qu'au manipulé.

Answer (score 2):

Une différence entre *crédulité* et *naïveté* réside entre la manipulation et la confiance, avec la guérison possible de la naïveté.

> C'est une personne *crédule*, on peut lui faire *croire* n'importe quoi, elle sera toujours victime des rhéteurs ; elle est influençable, voire manipulable.
>
> C'est un *naïf* il ne *connaît* pas le terrain sur lequel il s'engage, il va se faire avoir, au début il va *croire* tout ce qu'on lui dira, mais après "chat échaudé craint l'eau froide !"

Le *crédule* même échaudé retombera dans les futurs pièges tendus, alors que le *naïf* sera *déniaisé* par ses expériences.

Il est aussi vrai, comme dans les exemples cités, que la part émotionnelle du cœur humain peut rendre certaines personnes *naïves* avec une certaine candeur, alors que celles qui sont *crédules* ont un mental qui manquent de discernement.

 Ceci pour l'emploi originel des mots.

Mais lorsque le contexte est ironique, satyrique, ils deviennent facilement interchangeables ; avec peut-être un peu plus de méchanceté contre les *crédules* et un zeste d'empathie pour les *naïfs*.

Comment: Assez d'accord, toutefois je retirerai la notion de guérison possible pour la naïveté : Si la guérison est effectivement possible, le naïf n'assimile pas nécessairement ses expériences.

Answer (score 0):

Je crois que jusqu'à un certain point il s'agit de mot synonymes, mais ce sont les [collocations](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_%28linguistique%29) qui diffèrent plus que le sens lui-même.

Par exemple mon *Petit Robert* donne cette définition de *naïf*:

> qui est d'une **crédulité**, d'une confiance irraisonnée et quelque peu ridicule

De même, le Trésor de la langue française s.v. [*crédule*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%A9dule) et [*naïf*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/na%C3%AFf):

> Qui croit trop facilement et trop **naïvement** des choses même invraisemblables.
>
> Qui fait preuve (de trop) d'ingénuité, de confiance, de **crédulité**.

Si même les lexicographes professionnels ont de la difficulté à définir ces mots sans employer l'autre, je crois qu'on peut parler de synonymes!

Comment: Que veut dire « s.v. » ?

Comment: "à l'entrée" (*sub verbo*). Je n'aurais probablement pas dû employer un terme aussi technique ^_^;;

Comment: @Circeus  Plutôt que *collocation*, le *contexte* de la phrase semble plus adéquat, sinon quelle différence entre *naïf pathologique* et *crédule pathologique* ?

Answer (score 0):

*crédule* c'est croire ce qu'on lui dit,comme bobard bien étudié ; si on lui raconte une chose qu'il connait bien, il la refuse. Il peut mettre en doute par un autre sens : la vue et le toucher.

*Naif* c'est croire tout ce qu'il vit, ce qu'il voit, ce qu'il entend ; c'est  un caractère il reste tout le temps comme ça, il ne fait pas la différence entre  une vérité et un mensonge ; manipulé c'est pour ça qu'il est victime.